# Microsoft Active Accessibility Direct Annotation is not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, mfc, accessibility

Following MFC code sets accessible Name for popup menu item to "accessible text". It works on Windows 7/8 but on Windows 10 accessible name remains "item text".
Please help.

```
 CMenu menu1;
 menu1.CreatePopupMenu();
 menu1.AppendMenu(0, 1, TEXT("item text"));

 CComPtr<IAccPropServices> accPropServices;
 accPropServices.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AccPropServices, nullptr, CLSCTX_SERVER);
 accPropServices->SetHmenuPropStr(menu1, 1, PROPID_ACC_NAME, L"accessible text");
```

I check accessible properties with Window's SDK's inspect.exe